# Why does browser get Symbol.unscopables twice?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, with-statement

```js
with(new Proxy({}, {
  has() { return true },
  get(obj, key, proxy) { return console.log(String(key)) } })
) {
  a--
}
```

Output in Chrome:

```
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables)
a
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables)
```

Output in Firefox:

```
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables)
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables)
a
```

As I understand, one getting is related to reading value and the other - to assigning.

<s>It's logical that `a--` should write to the same place where `a` was read from.</s> No, it's not.

But getting value for `Symbol.unscopables` twice hints us, that it's possible to pass one object for reading and the other one for writing.

Is it really meant to work like that? What does specification say?

Actually, it almost works in Chrome and FF - it's possible to read from one obect and to write into the other one, but it leads to different results:

Update: Safari 10 reads it only once.

```js
var a, b, flag = true

with (a = { x: 7 })
  with (b = { x: 4, get [Symbol.unscopables]() { return { x: flag=!flag } } })
    x++

                 // Chrome   FF       Safari   Edge
console.log(a)   // {x:5}    {x:7}    {x:7}    {x:5}
console.log(b)   // {x:4}    {x:8}    {x:5}    {x:4}
```

PS: [Same question in Russian](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/590895/178988)

Comment: Why would you ever mix `with` and modern features? `with` will not show up in idiomatic JS.

Comment: @ssube, you can even ask why am I changing `unscopables` dynamically, but I'm just interested how it should work. No any real-life examples. Maybe only somewhere for codegolf competitions :)

Comment: @Gothdo, it's not related to proxy. Proxy just explicitly shows, that the value is taken twice. But the later example workes without any proxies.

Comment: that would have been the follow-up, but if this is for the sake of science, carry on and good luck. ;) Just please don't use `with` in real life.

Comment: _"`console.log(b)   // {x:4}    {x:8}`"_ At firefox 47 for second example `console.log(JSON.stringify(b))` returns `{"x":5,"undefined":{"x":true}}`

Comment: @guest271314, FF48+ [is required](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-well-known_symbols_Symbol.unscopables).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per spec, @@unscopables should be read only once for "x++", a far as I can tell.  See details in https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2017-February/047725.html

So both Chrome and Firefox are buggy here.  Safari gets this right.

See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1341061 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5992